# Cause: path may not be null or empty string. path=''

Tags: android, linphone

I am trying to open [linphone-android](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android) library  but I am getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path may not be null or empty string. path=''
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractBaseDirFileResolver.doResolve(AbstractBaseDirFileResolver.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:226)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:143)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:203)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$1.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree$FilteredFileTree.visitContents(CompositeFileTree.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveNested(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCollections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileCollectionConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCollections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.isEmpty(CompositeFileCollection.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:596)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

Comment: Are you set any path of this `RELEASE_STORE_FILE=""` ?

Comment: set the value of the *path* parameter. You are sending it as blank

Comment: yes RELEASE_STORE_FILE=""

Comment: which path i have to set?

Comment: It will be your app keystore file URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You provided the keystore path is `""`. Check `gradle.properties` file it have this `RELEASE_STORE_FILE=""`. `""` will be replaced by your keystore path. If you don't need now then simply remove those lines and check.

Comment: what is default value of RELEASE_STORE_FILE

Comment: There is not a default path for this. During debugging you can remove those lines. When you want to create signed APK then you need to create a keystore file. When you have the file then add aging those lines and set the path of that keystore file.

Comment: if i remove this line from gradle.properties in gradel i get this error               
            Could not get unknown property 'RELEASE_STORE_FILE' for SigningConfig_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=null, storePassword=null, keyAlias=null, keyPassword=null, storeType=null, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig.

Comment: I think the keywords are linked with other places. Please keep those lines and generate a keystore file for this and set the path.

Comment: without a first clean gradle signed apk not generating

Comment: Create e new project and run first. Then create a keystore file and add that file on your current project. Also update the path.

Comment: I had set key store path but still getting same error.

Comment: I am getting error "Cause: path may not be null or empty string. path=''" when I am importing the downloaded project from git.

Comment: Would you please share the git repository url?

Comment: I have downloaded the project from this link: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android#compilation-instructions,

Comment: RELEASE_STORE_FILE="D:\\Demos\\linphone-android-master\\keystore.jks"
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=1234
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=google
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=1234

 in gradle.property file

Comment: RELEASE_STORE_FILE="D:\\Demos\\linphone-android-master\\keystore.jks"  not a proper way. This setting is optional you can try to remove and run again.

Comment: Or follow this instruction  
1. Place the my-release-key.keystore file under the android/app directory in your project folder.
2. Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties or android/gradle.properties, and add the following (replace ***** with the correct keystore password, alias and key password),
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.jks
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias

Comment: Faysal I have also tried 2nd option still same result.
RELEASE_STORE_FILE="appdemo.keystore"
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=1234
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=google
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=1234

Answer (score 3):

If you are using React native with EXPO, run this:

```
npx expo prebuild --platform android --clean
```

to regenerate the android directory

Answer (score 0):

Don't try open it from android studio. It's C language files with automatic build. Read [readme](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android#compilation-instructions)