# Can't build javadoc anymore after upgrading from JDK 1.6, "path may not be null or empty string"

Tags: java, android, gradle, javadoc

I used to use the following Gradle task in `build.gradle` to build Javadocs for my Android app:

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    title = "My Docs v${android.defaultConfig.versionName}"
    failOnError false
    options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    destinationDir = file("${project.rootDir}/docs/")
    classpath += android.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath + android.sourceSets.main.output
    // classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))

    // packages to exclude from the docs
    exclude "com/example/README*"

    // workaround for https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19726 when using "exclude"/"include"
    options.addStringOption("-source-path", android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.join(":"))
}
```

However, this no longer works after upgrading from Gradle 7 and JDK 1.6 to Gradle 8 and JDK 17. I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':example:javadoc'.
> path may not be null or empty string. path=''
```

When I uncomment the line with the `android.getBootClasspath()`, I get other errors like:

```
…/Example.java:21: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.Log;
```

Looking at related questions these all don't apply, or the fixes there do not work:

- [Cause: path may not be null or empty string. path=''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075340/cause-path-may-not-be-null-or-empty-string-path)
- [A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > path may not be null or empty string. path='null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457245/a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-app-path-may-not-be-null-or-empty-st)
- [Cannot build my android studio project on another PC, gradle says "Cause: path may not be null or empty string. path='null'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971861/cannot-build-my-android-studio-project-on-another-pc-gradle-says-cause-path-m)
- [ERROR: path may not be null or empty string. path='null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335308/error-path-may-not-be-null-or-empty-string-path-null)
- [Android proguard issue: path may not be null or empty string. path='null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387761/android-proguard-issue-path-may-not-be-null-or-empty-string-path-null)
- https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22584

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be to remove these lines:

```
classpath += android.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath + android.sourceSets.main.output
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
```

And instead add this:

```
classpath += files("${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar")
```

This seems to fix the issue with JDK 17.

Hat tip to https://github.com/emanuele-f for providing this solution.